# View not found after publish to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have created an ASP.NET MVC Core project and registered some custom folders to search for Views. I did this with a custom `IViewLocationExpander` class like this:

```
public class AppsViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
  public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, 
                                               IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
  {
    yield return "/MyViewLocation/A/Views";
    //and so on...
  }
```

And used this class in *Startup.cs*:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new AppsViewLocationExpander());
    });
}
```

Inside the *MyViewLocation/A/Views* folder are some **.cshtml* files and a local debug session proceeded **without any error**.
Now I published the web app to Azure, and I got a 500 Internal Server Error. I Attached Visual Studio to debug this error and got this message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>   /MyViewLocation/A/Views/Index.cshtml

**What did I wrong?** Do I have to add the Views-Folder in some other place too?

**EDIT**:
I modified my *project.json* at my initial setup, but this does not help with my Azure problem. But probably it was necessary to find the views during my local debugging.

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "Areas/**/Views",
    "MyViewLocation/**/Views",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ]
},
```

**EDIT 2**:
I uploaded manually the **.cshtml* files onto the FTP server. Nevertheless They are still not found.

Comment: Are the view files deployed to the web app or are they missing?

Comment: @DavidG I cannot find them on the FTP, so I think hey are missing. Is it here necessary to modify the deployment script?

Comment: What is the `Build Action` for the view files set to? (i.e. in the properties of the file in Visual Studio)

Comment: @DavidG The Properties Window shows only _File Name_ and _Full Path_ for all files. Has this todo with .NET core/the new Visual Studio project structure?

Comment: Ah yes, good point! So the files should just copy over. How are you deploying?

Comment: @DavidG I used the publish dialog with standard configuration and selected _Web Deploy_ as my publishing method.

Comment: @DavidG I tried to upload the _*.cshtml_ files manually to the FTP server but they still not found. Have you an idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 8):

> System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched: /MyViewLocation/A/Views/Index.cshtml

The error message shows that there are some files missing when deploy to Azure. I have tested this scenario in my local, every things works fine. If you encounter this problem, I would recommend to publish the folder again like the following:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was losing it with this issue. Slight side note, this context menu option was only available for me in the Publish view, so after I right clicked the App and hit Publish. Subsequently right clicking the views folder made this context option available to me.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in .NET Core 2.2 and it was settings in **.csproj*. Somehow accidentally I excluded the View from publishing.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Remove="Views\ToDos\Edit.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After I removed the lines above from project settings, the view was published.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same symptom, but a different cause.  In my case, the view that was missing from Azure had gone missing from the project file.  This means it wasn't found on the Solution Explorer, either.  With dozens of similarly-named views, one missing view wasn't easy to spot.  Not being in the project file meant that the view file wasn't published to Azure.

The view's .cshtml file did exist in the project directory, however, so it was found when I ran the application locally.  And I was able to restore it to the project file  by right-clicking on the **Views** folder in Solution Explorer, then clicking **Add**, then clicking on **Existing Item...**.

After the view was restored to the project, and the corrected project published to Azure, the view worked again.